Go exception: No routes for location error
I am getting the following error: GoException: no routes for location: com.googleusercontent.apps.1052157635-94tcrdep4q1r9g3gvi5dvllrejmali://firebaseauth/link?deep_link_id=https%3A%2F%2Ftonns-a06e3.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fcallback%3FauthType%3DsignInWithRedirect%26link%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftonns-a06e3.firebaseapp.com%252F__%252Fauth%252Fhandler%253Fstate%253DAMbdmDlHduq-oYEjfP-Iey_XlGlyF61HK5tRsirFPGToxun0b165nOXoI51r9kzyUqaKTEpMiVtopoFLf6Ew6EvqJq0_VB4WY4_gxGLf4aRdLZ__KyW5S9FAY2l3bprsJwRe1iZXcZRxuBWLHNoMBw8Iu_P5mrsdxwXACiggwXTDEqagN5LDQ1ucxGs0SFJ4H4nHOmxmhHv0GrQrcDASHXhJZq3hJRLWAouW2Rn7Pq9nf-XOPsZ9R7nqOicBYG5go1BxAtvqBr_BbcEdbpvb_iprWGYL-RP0h9UdYeHYEhG6WhA1veuzBq0d3lirXYzbumylCyW4mTzJzdvIn9RR0TBF8mcyN_6WYvgLZhAt96b2UxG0Z4_6lw%2526code%253D4%25252F0AeanS0YosOSB-cJCOyK9e7ttvob8I1stlJRbqo7leg_5gK2FqtSZ2Sjn9v-rriDL7mnrYQ%2526scope%253Demail%252520openid%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.googleapis.com%25252Fauth%25252Fuserinfo.email%2526authuser%253D0%2526prompt%253Dnone%26eventId%3DTYKPLUZAAI. 
My gorouter for firebase auth link is defined as follows: 
   GoRoute(
        path: '/firebaseauth/link',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          debugPrint('Firebase Auth Link');
          final queryParams = state.uri.queryParameters;

          if (queryParams.containsKey('error')) {
            return const ErrorPage();
          } else {
            return AuthWall(
              buildSuccessScreen: (_) {
                return Container();
              },
              screenTitle: StringConfig.login.title,
              screenDescription: StringConfig.login.screenDescription,
            );
          }
        },
      ), 
Why do I get this error? My info.plist file is as follows: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>tonns</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>XXXX</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your camera to take photos and videos.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need your location to provide better services both in the foreground and background.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need your location to provide better services even when the app is in the background.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need your location to provide better services.</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your microphone to record audio during sessions.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your photo library to save photos.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>We need access to your photo library to save and access photos.</string>
    <key>NSUserNotificationAlertStyle</key>
    <string>Alert</string>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>location</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>

    <!-- Add the custom URL scheme -->
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.105XXX3657635-94tcrdep4q1r9g3gvi8b5dvllrejmali</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

Is the go router defined correctly? Does that need to be changed?
Is the go router defined correctly? Does that need to be changed?
Is the go router defined correctly? Does that need to be changed?
Is the go router defined correctly? Does that need to be changed?
Is the go router defined correctly? Does that need to be changed?

Did you  implemented  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); ?
Here you have many option to implement routes and auth...
https://stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/77249590/how-to-handle-authentication-in-flutter-with-go-router-and-firebase-authenticati?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=pt&_x_tr_hl=pt-BR&_x_tr_pto=sc

Based on the solutions, I have implemented as follows: Future main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(
options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
final router = MyAppRouts().router;
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
router.refresh();
});
runApp(const MyApp());
}. But I still get the same error.

But when I restart again, it gets logged in.
